# self.tableView.reloadData triggers, but table remains empty

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I am probably missing something super obvious. For some reason my new UITableViewController is not populating.

I stepped through it, "viewDidAppear" fires up when I access my new UITableViewController through the simulator. The "IF" triggers to true and coursesToWatch gets assigned.  Code then executes self.tableView.reloadData() but nothing happens. Table view remains blank, there are no errors or exceptions.

I have changed rowIdentifier to "Cell" in the new UITableViewController. What else am I missing?

```
class WatchListViewController: UITableViewController {
var coursesToWatch = [ReportingFacility]()

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var dataFile:NSURL = FileSystemHelper.pathForDocumentsFile("watchlist.data")
    if let possibleCourses = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(dataFile.path) as? [ReportingFacility]{
        if(possibleCourses.count != 0) {
            coursesToWatch = possibleCourses
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    if(coursesToWatch.count != 0) {
        var currentCourse = coursesToWatch[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel.text = currentCourse.name

    }
    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: What about the values in currentCourse.name. Instead of using currentCourse.name in cell.textLabel.text use a static string then check the table whwther its displaying the static value or not

Comment: Did you implemented [tableView(_: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:)?

Comment: @Mike S Yep. Its still not working though.                                                             override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

Comment: @Balaji I wasn't able to trigger the tableView func. How would I do that? It doesn't get called at all.

Comment: IS it called before the self.tableview.reloaddata

Comment: can u create table view using IBOutlet or programmatically?

Answer (score -1):

May be it's helpful.It's work for me.

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        // let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Datacell") as UITableViewCell
        // tableCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: nil)

```
    let CellIdentifier : NSString! = "Cell"
    tableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

    if(tableCell == nil){
         tableCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
    }


    if(dataIsEmpty == true){
         tableCell.textLabel.text = "No Information Found !!!"
    }else{
    //    var aryDataStr : NSString! = dataAry[indexPath.row].valueForKey("name") as NSString!
    //    println("aryDataStr : \(aryDataStr)")

        if(selectedString == dataAry[indexPath.row].valueForKey("name") as NSString!){
            tableCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        }else{
            tableCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        }
        tableCell.textLabel.text = dataAry[indexPath.row].valueForKey("name") as NSString!
    }
```

}